# Way to compare two excel files and CSV file

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, comparison

I need to compare two excel files and a csv file, then write some data from one excel file to another.

It looks like this:

- CSV file with names which I will compare. For example (spam, eggs)
- First Excel file with name and value of it. For example (spam, 100)
- Second Excel file with name. For example (eggs)

Now, when I input file (second) into program I need to ensure that eggs == spam with csv file and then save value of 100 to the eggs.

For operating on excel files I'm using `openpyxl` and for csv I'm using `csv`.

Can I count on your help? Maybe there are better libraries to do that, because my trials proved to be a total failure.

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. We are not a code writing service. See [our help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on info how to write a good question. Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck and we're happy to help.

Comment: I didnt asked for solution of problem, but for libraries that will do that kind of job...

Comment: We can't help you to find other libraries if you don't explain why the mentioned libraries don't work. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: I finally got it by myself, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by myself. Some complex way, but it works like I wanted to. Will be glad for some tips to it.

```
import openpyxl
import numpy as np

lines = np.genfromtxt("csvtest.csv", delimiter=";", dtype=None)
compdict = dict()
for i in range(len(lines)):
    compdict[lines[i][0]] = lines[i][1]

wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook('inputtest.xlsx')

wb2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='spistest.xlsx')

ws = wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

spis = wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=ws.max_row, min_col=1):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value in compdict:
            for wiersz in spis.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=spis.max_row, min_col=1):
                for komorka in wiersz:
                    if komorka.value == compdict[cell.value]:
                        cena = spis.cell(row=komorka.row, column=2)
                        ws.cell(row=cell.row, column=2, value=cena.value)

wb1.save('inputtest.xlsx')
wb2.close()
```